# Were the eirev rav Jewish?

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, yetziat-mitzrayim

Were the *eirev rav* Jewish? If they were in fact Jewish why are they described by the term *eirev rav* instead of just referring to them as we would any other Jew? If they were not Jewish why were they not cast out after repeatedly causing trouble?

[Possibly related topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13749/what-happened-to-the-eirev-rav)

Comment: They could have been Jews. "Eirev Rav" was their name like Reubenites, Shimonites, etc.

Comment: @ShmuelBrill Don't forget the Issacharites and the Zebulonites! :)

Comment: Only one tribe, the tribe of Yehuda, was actually Jewish at that point (or ever). Everyone else was Israelite.

Comment: ...Huh??  Please clarify what you mean by your use of the word "Jewish".

Comment: @Gary, I think he's using it literally. Unnecessarily so, IMO.

Comment: so...the B'nai Yehudas were the only Yehudim ever? No wonder the Persians named the province Yehud...I wonder when the Judeans became Jews....Hasmonean times?

Comment: @Gary, to ask Adam Mosheh, tag him like so...

Comment: @AdamMosheh, ping.

Comment: @Gary The first mention of "Jew" (Yehudi) that I am aware of is in Megillas Esther 2:5. Ish Yehudi ... Ushmo Mordechai ... Ish Yemini (from the tribe of Binyamin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rashi in Parshas Bo 12:38](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=168&hilite=) says that it was a mixture of converts that went out together with the Jews. Perhaps it was difficult to cast them out as there were bona fide Jews that were also part of the Erev Rav.

Answer (score 3):

They stood at Mount Sinai when the Torah was given, so I would think that it was given to them too, as they were then part of the nation.  Also, if they were Egyptians, they did not drown in the sea - so they must have become Jewish.  Perhaps accepting the Torah allowed them to become Jewish.  And if they were not Jewish, then they likely died during the generation of the desert because they would also have spoken badly about the land.  Interesting question though.

Answer (score -2):

They were from the Jews that Hashem wanted to kill at the plague of darkness so Moshe begged Hashem to give them a chance and this is what happened

Comment: Hi. How do you know this? Do you have a source for this? If so you should [edit] that citation into the post, as none of us know you that we should take your word for it.

Comment: Hi Friedman and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Did you get a chance to look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) already? Also note that Mi Yodeya is big on sources so we can trace back what you say. Please stay around and keep learning with us!