# Are the airuv rav compared to tza'ras?

Tags: gentiles, sources-mekorot, egypt, tzaraas-negaim

Looking for a source in chazal that compare the airuv rav  to tza'ras.

I have vague recollection of learning something to this effect once and it would make a killer addition to my Shavuos dvar torah.

Comment: Please add some information about why you suspect such a source might exist.

Comment: I have vague recollection of learning something to this effect once and it would make a killer addition to my shavuos dvar torah

Comment: Thanks for that information. I've added it to your question. If you can [edit] in any more information about where you may have heard this, it will help people help you.

Comment: @IsaacMoses i've got to meet you one day

Comment: Partial opportunity coming soon: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1078/2

Answer (score 3):

Try [Panim Yafot on Bamidbar 5:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39321&st=&pgnum=128&hilite=)

Alternatively, if you assume [the Erev Rav were originally not Jewish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14473/759) then you can apply the statement ([Kiddushin 70b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=70b&format=pdf)): קשין גרים לישראל כספחת